# 3 month average not showing right results

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate 3 month average from current month(that means june,july,august) in sql but not getting correct values. Not understanding whats happening.

```
EMAIL           ORDERDATE   PRICE
xyz@gmail.com   7/30/2019   55.42
xyz@gmail.com   7/27/2019   66.06
xyz@gmail.com   5/7/2019    56.48
abc@yahoo.com   8/2/2019    66.99
abc@yahoo.com   8/1/2019    200.87
abc@yahoo.com   7/25/2019   112.22
abc@yahoo.com   6/24/2019   323.65
abc@yahoo.com   5/7/2019    55.6
```

This is how ouput is calculated: it is not sum..for first emailaddress we have sales history of only july and nothing in june or august..so it is (55.42+66.06)/1, and then we have sales history in june, july, august (66.99+ 200.87+ 112.22+323.65)/3..as it is 3 month average..hope this makes it more clear

```
 output required:
    email                  avg
    xyz@gmail.com        121.48
    abc@yahoo.com        234.57
```

code I used:

```
    select 
    mo.Email,
    aVG(case when mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())  then 
   (mo.Price) END )AS 'Average_3Months'
    from Order mo
    group by
    mo.Email
```

Comment: Well, you may be referencing different columns. In your query, you put `mo.OrderDateTime`, but your output shows `ORDERDATE`.  Same thing with `mo.TotalPrice` vs `PRICE`.  Maybe wrong table??

Comment: You say you want an average but your required output is a sum.

Comment: @Eric fixed the query to show right table.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: what you are showing for expected output is not the average for the emails ... for the xyz email,  that would be (55.42+66.06)/2=60.74 ... 121.48 is the SUM

Comment: @bernie..it is not sum..for first emailaddress we have sales history of only july and nothing in june or august..so it is (55.42+66.06)/1, and then we have sales history in june, july, august (66.99+ 200.87+ 112.22+323.65)/3..as it is 3 month average..hope this makes it more clear

Comment: How can the average of 55.42 and 66.06 = 121.48?

Comment: @BWS..we are not counting in May..please see my comment above to help it understand better.

Comment: i modified my comment above ...

Comment: If you want a true 3 month average, then the denominator is always going to be 3, for any sales person, regardless if they have or don't have any sales in the corresponding months. `xyz@gmail.com` will give a false average if you calculate the way you are doing now.

Comment: @WEI_DBA..Months which dont have any sales need to be excluded

Answer (score 1):

This is not the usual way to calculate an average and for sure you can't do it with AVG():

```
select 
  mo.Email,
  sum(case when mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then mo.Price END) / 
  count(distinct case when mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then month(mo.orderdate) END)
  as 'Average_3Months'
from [order] mo
group by mo.Email
```

Or simpler:

```
select 
  mo.Email,
  sum(mo.Price) / count(distinct month(mo.orderdate)) as 'Average_3Months'
from [order] mo
where mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
group by mo.Email
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e37ac0acb348d1bc296739188637309).

Results:

```
> Email         |  Average_3Months
> :------------ | ---------------:
> abc@yahoo.com | 234.576666666667
> xyz@gmail.com |           121.48
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try finding the sum first then divide by the count like below:

```
;with cte as (
    select 
    mo.Email,
    sum(case when mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then 
    (mo.Price) else 0 END ) AS 'Sum_3Months',
    sum(case when mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then 
    1 else 0 END ) AS 'Sum_3Months_Count'
    from Order mo
    group bymo.Email
)
select Email, Sum_3Months/Sum_3Months_Count as Avg_3months
from cte
where Sum_3Months_Count>0
group by Email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        mo.Email,
        SUM(mo.Price)/COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(mo.orderDate))  AS 'Average_3Months'
FROM [Order] mo
WHERE mo.OrderDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP BY mo.Email
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below script with sub query. The condition for OrderDate will always consider from the 1 day of 3rd Previous month to Today. Here OrderDate is checking >= '2019-June-01' and its calculated automatically from GETDATE() that is Today.

```
SELECT A.EMAIL,AVG(A.monthly_total) Average_of_Month 
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(OrderDate) MN, mo.Email,
    SUM(price ) monthly_total
    FROM your_table mo
    WHERE OrderDate >= CAST(DATEADD(MM,-2,DATEADD(DD,-(DATEPART(Day,GETDATE()))+1,GETDATE())) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate),mo.Email
)A
GROUP BY A.EMAI
```